# Tension in pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, free-body-diagram, string

I am asked to calculate the tension in the rope of a pendulum at (a) its initial position as well as at (b) its lowest position.

$L = 3 m$

$α = 10^o$

$mass = 2kg$

(a) For the intial point I used the equation:
$T=mg \cos (\alpha)$

and got the answer $T=19.3N$

(b) To calculate the tension at the lowest point I need to use the equation: $T=mg +mv^2/r$

however since I am not given the velocity I can't use that equation, so how do I calculate the tension at (b)?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Unfortunately, [homework-like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633) questions are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer conceptual questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem? Also mention any thoughts you currently have about the solution, and your assessment of their usefulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a homework question, I won't provide the full solution, but here is a guide.

Gravitational potential energy is converted to kinetic energy. Thus, we apply conservation of energy to obtain the velocity:
$$mgL(1- \cos{\alpha}) = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
You should be able to calculate the tension from there.